# How to receive data from a Tcp/Ip connection in a webots controller?

Tags: python, sockets, webots

I'm doing a project in the WEBOTS simulator and right now I'm implementing a TCP/IP communication to be able to pass information between controllers. In particular I have two controllers, one of them is the server and the other is the client. My problem appears when I need to receive the data sent by the server in the client controller, because I have a function that receives the data inside the while loop and while this function does not receive data it stays there and this makes the simulation not progress . This is the problem, the function that receives information, for the purpose of the project I need the controller to be always ready to receive information.

I leave here a print of the code of my client controller, as the information reception function is inside the while loop, while the function does not receive information, the simulation remains stopped.[Print of the code in client controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3HaK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: # Main loop:
while robot.step(1) != -1:      # Steps of 1ms
    msg = receive()  # Here I receive a velocity (Blcoking)

    drive_omni_wheel(0, 0)